# KDE Ubuntu 18.04 scaling lower than 1

Tags: kde, 18.04, scale-mode

I have 17" display with Full HD resolution and I need to use smaller scaling than 1, because icons are to big for me.

Where I can change it - modify config file - to have such possibility in settings ?

- Unity offer scaling lower than one,
- Gnome can do it (settings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']")
- List item
- But KDE I didn't find a way